# If $d(x) = f(x)*u(x)+g(x)*v(x)$ $d(x) $ is gcd of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, analysis, polynomials

If $d(x) = f(x)*u(x)+g(x)*v(x)$ $d(x) $ is gcd of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
Then proof that $d(x) = f(x)*u_1(x)+g(x)*v_1(x)$ where $u_1(x)$ is remainder when $u(x)$ dividing by $g_1(x)=\frac{g(x)}{d(x)}$  and where $v_1(x)$ is remainder when $v(x)$ dividing by $f_1(x)=\frac{f(x)}{d(x)}$

I don't have any idea . Can you help?

Comment: You may see this not as a function but as a normal variable as function's value at different $x$ doesn't interact. Now try seeing why $(u - u_1)f + (v - v_1)g$ should be $0$.

Comment: I may be wrong but I just don't believe this is true unless the quotients when you do the two divisions add to $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of this is over a field (the reals, for instance), and that neither $f$ nor $g$ are zero. The idea then is to write out what division means, and to look at the degrees.

Set $\bar f = f/d$, $\bar g = g/d$.

Therefore, $u = a \bar g + u_1$, and with $\deg u_1 < \deg \bar g$, and $v= b\bar f + v_1$, with $\deg v_1 < \deg \bar f$.
Substituting into the original equation, one gets
$$d = a\bar g f + b\bar f g + u_1f+v_1g= d(a+b)\bar g\bar f + d( u_1\bar f+v_1\bar g).$$
Divide by $d$ to get
$$1 = (a+b)\bar g\bar f + ( u_1\bar f+v_1\bar g).$$

Now, $$\deg (u_1\bar f+v_1\bar g)\le \max (\deg (u_1\bar f), \deg (v_1 \bar g))< \deg (\bar f \bar g).$$  Hence $(a+b)=0$, and the result follows.

If this was not entirely clear, assume $d=1$, so that $\bar f = f$ and $\bar g =g$, so that one can skip the overlining...

Note: $\deg 0 = -\infty$.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't have accepted quite so quickly... But: if $(a+b)\not =0$, then the term $(a+b)\bar f \bar g$ has degree at least $ \deg (\bar f \bar g)$, and the other term is of lower degree - so you can't add the two terms to get $1$ - unless!!!  and here I made a mistake - $\bar f$ and $\bar g$ are constants, so the other term is $0$. But that's a special case of $d= f= g$ (up to multiplicative constants) - where the result can actually fail. For instance , $d=f=g=(x-1)$, and $(x-1) = 1/2(x-1) + 1/2(x-1)$, then  $u_1= 0, v_1=0$ (since $1/2= 1/2\cdot 1 + 0$ and the result fails....

Comment: @rha please see my above comment! The result holds - and the argument is valid - assuming that the non-zero $d$, $f$, and $g$ are not all equal, up to multiplicative  constant.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, please see the above - along with my correction/caveat comment, where, as it so happens, the counterexample/special case falls much in line with your comment. Sigh.

Comment: Ok thank you and I looked textbook there was written $deg u_1(x)$ $<$ $deg g(x)$ - $deg d(x)$ and same with $v_1(x)$ so this is my typo sorry)).